# How much does it cost to fix headlights and window up/down button?

Tags: headlight, wiring, power-windows, oldsmobile

I drive a 1990 Oldsmobile regency My headlights no longer work all of a sudden. My brights still work fine. Why did this happen?

Also, the window up/down button on the passenger side no longer works too. I don't know what's going on please help!

Comment: Welcome to the site. As it stands, your question is more about cost rather than repair/maintenance, which is going to be extremely difficult to answer objectively. I suggest you modify the question to ask what could be wrong instead. The cost will be much easier for you to figure out on your own once you know what might be broken

Comment: You can use the 'edit' button to modify the question

Comment: I don't think its that hard to open up a door panel so that you can take a look at the wiring/button for the window. There are some tutorials for this online.

Answer (score 1):

If both headlights cease to work at the same time, this leads us to the idea that the fault is probably not in the bulbs, but in some part that is on a common path between the electrical supply and the lights. Some points you could take a look at are:

- Fuse! This is probably the easiest explanation. Take a look in your fuse box (often under the dash, between the driver's legs and the door). Most fuse boxes nowadays have a guide of which fuse serves which circuit, otherwise your car's user guide should also have a diagram.
- If your car is equipped with a relay to control the headlights, that could also be at fault. However, this is used mostly for upgraded lights, and I doubt a standard setup will have one.
- The headlights switch. Sometimes, this degrades due to use and needs to be replaced. The fact that the long beams comes on means one position of this switch still works, but perhaps not the other.

You say your power windows have also failed at the same time. This could also very easily be related to a blown fuse. So my first stop in diagnosing this would definitely be the fuse box. If it is just that, then you are lucky since fuses are cheap!

Hope this helps.